# Writing unicode regex for both Python2 and Python3

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode

I can use the `ur'something'` and the `re.U` flag in Python2 to compile a regex pattern, e.g.:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 18 2016, 07:03:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(ur'(«)', re.U)
>>> s = u'«abc «def«'
>>> re.sub(pattern, r' \1 ', s)
u' \xab abc  \xab def \xab '
>>> print re.sub(pattern, r' \1 ', s)
 « abc  « def «
```

In Python3, I can avoid the `u'something'` and even the `re.U` flag:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct 11 2016, 04:59:56) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(«)')
>>> s = u'«abc «def«'
>>> print( re.sub(pattern, r' \1 ', s))
 « abc  « def «
```

But the goal is to write the regex such that it supports both Python2 and Python3. And doing `ur'something'` in Python3 would result in a syntax error:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(ur'(«)', re.U)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pattern = re.compile(ur'(«)', re.U)
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Since it's a syntax error, even checking versions before declaring the pattern wouldn't work in Python3:

```
>>> import sys
>>> _pattern = r'(«)' if sys.version_info[0] == 3 else ur'(«)'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    _pattern = r'(«)' if sys.version_info[0] == 3 else ur'(«)'
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**How to unicode regex to support both Python2 and Python3?**

---

Although `r' '` could easily be replaced by `u' '` by dropping the literal string in this case.

There are complicated regexes that sort of requires the `r' '` for sanity sake, e.g.

```
re.sub(re.compile(r'([^\.])(\.)([\]\)}>"\'»]*)\s*$', re.U), r'\1 \2\3 ', s)
```

So the solution should include the literal string `r' '` usage unless there're other ways to get around it. But do note that using string literals or `unicode_literals` or from `__future__` is undesired since it will cause tonnes of other problems, esp. in other parts of the code base that I work with, see http://python-future.org/unicode_literals.html

For specific reason why the code base discourages unicode_literals import but uses the `r' '` notation is because filled with it and making changes to each one of them is going to be extremely painful, e.g.

- https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/treebank.py
- https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/moses.py

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but for this case, it doesn't seem like you actually _need_ a raw string... IOW, `u'(«)'` should work fine ...

Comment: Ah ha, see updated question.

Comment: Could `re.escape` can replace the raw string usage? Something like `re.compile(re.escape(u'([^\.])(\.)([\]\)}>"\'»]*)\s*$'), re.U)`?

Comment: I don't think `re.escape` can really help you. It's a pity they don't support the `ur` prefix, but I guess they wanted to limit the number of prefixes, and after all, Python 2 doesn't have to be supported for eternity. – Why don't you use the future `unicode_literals` on a module basis, eg. only for those files that actually contain a lot of complex regexes? For the rest, it seems you'll have to double the backslashes...

Comment: @lenz it's because I'm not sure how much of the `nltk` would `unicode_literals` break esp. in `nltk.tokenize.__init__.py`. It seems to be a can of worms.

Comment: `nltk.tokenize.__init__` has, like, 6 string literals (all regex patterns), three of which are already unicode. Leaves you three strings to test. (`unicode_literals` doesn't affect anything that is imported.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need raw strings? For your example, a unicode string is needed, but not a raw string.  Raw strings are a convenience, but not required - just double any `\` you would use in the raw string and use plain unicode.

Python 2 allows concatenating a raw string with a unicode string (resulting in a unicode string), so you could use `r'([^\.])(\.)([\]\)}>"\'' u'»' r']*)\s*$'`
In Python 3, they will all be unicode, so that will work too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I ended up doing something like this using the dangerous eval() function.  It know it's not pretty, but it allows my code to work in both Python 2 and Python 3.

```
if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    pattern = eval("re.compile(ur'(\u00ab)', re.U)")
else:
    pattern = re.compile(r'(«)', re.U)
```